# Importing multiple files containing functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, include, export

I have this tree:

```
/areas
    first.js
    second.js
/lib
    /first
        stuffA.js
        stuffB.js
    /second
        otherStuff01.js
        otherStuff02.js
    /utils
        commonStuff01.js
        commonStuff02.js
test.js
```

- `first.js` and `second.js` contains **functions** that are **executed** in `test.js`;
- all the **files** in `/lib/first` are **used** in `first.js`
- all the **files** in `/lib/second` are **used** in `second.js`
- **files** in `/lib/utils` are used in **multiple places**, e.g. print functions and similar.

Since the `/areas` folder will be enriched with **a lot of files** in the future, is there a smart way in **JS** to `exports` and `require` files in `test.js` to avoid a ton of `require` lines?

_

e.g. I want to **avoid** in `test.js`

```
const first = require('./areas/first')
const second = require('./areas/second')
...
```

I have to import other files in `first.js` and `second.js` too, so suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: you can use indes.js files in the folders, in this files you export everything from the other files.

Comment: how about generating the paths to the files and iterating through (pseudocode): script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.type = 'text/javascript';
script_tag.src = "here the iterated element goes"

etc.

Comment: @Kuechlin do I need to create an index.js for each main folder? I mean one in `/areas` and one in `/lib`?

Comment: @Uni_x Sounds like a good idea but I'm not sure where to put this code :|

Comment: @Diego Well I'm a beginner myself. I think it should be at the entry point like index.js

Comment: I put a index file in every directory. I automated this with a powershell script. You will have lots of these index files with node js.